# Find : $\sqrt[6]{\frac{\sqrt{2}+(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)^7}{(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)^{11}}}$ in its algebraic form.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find : $$\sqrt[6]{\frac{\sqrt{2}+(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)^7}{(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)^{11}}}$$ in its algebraic form.

Now, I kinda think it would not be wise to try to expand this, but rather apply de Moivre formula on the complex number in the numerator and denominator, then simplify that complex number within the root, and once again apply moivres formula.

I have tried but then I get the expression:$\sqrt[6]{\frac{\sqrt{2}+\cos{\frac{21 \pi}{4}+i\sin{\frac{21 \pi }{4}}}}{\cos \frac{11\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{11 \pi}{4}}}$ and don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Well, why have't you tried it then?

Comment: Check out my update

Comment: i got $$1 e^{\frac{i \pi }{6}}$$

Comment: can you give me a clue, where to go from where I stopped?

Comment: If you want to use sine and cosine, consider evaluating what you currently have, then rationalizing the fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt at a solution using complex exponentials...

$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt[6]{\frac{\sqrt{2}+(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)^7}{(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)^{11}}} &= 
\sqrt[6]{\frac{\sqrt{2}+\left(e^{i3\pi/4}\right)^7}{\left(e^{i\pi/4}\right)^{11}}} 
\\
& = \sqrt[6]{\frac{\sqrt{2}+e^{i21\pi/4}}{e^{i11\pi/4}}}
\\
& = \sqrt[6]{\sqrt{2}e^{-i11\pi/4}+e^{i10\pi/4}}
\\
& = \sqrt[6]{\sqrt{2}e^{-i3\pi/4}+e^{i\pi/2}}
\\
& = \sqrt[6]{\sqrt{2}\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\color{red}{-}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i\right)+i}
\\
& = \color{green}{\sqrt[6]{-1}}
\end{align*} $$

Now take the root, again using complex exponentials. Take care, though, as the root is multivalued. *You ought to find six distinct points, as this is a sixth root of unity*. Let me know if anything looks iffy.

EDIT: I checked the answer with Wolfram. I made a sign error above (red). The green result works out.

Comment: The imaginary part of what you have in parentheses on the next to last line should be negative. Then you have the same result I have.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**        $$\cos\left(\dfrac{21}{4}\pi\right)=\cos\left(\left(\dfrac{20}{4}+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)\pi\right),\ \,\sin\left(\dfrac{21}{4}\pi\right)=\sin\left(\left(\dfrac{20}{4}+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)\pi\right),\\ \cos\left(\dfrac{11}{4}\pi\right)=\cos\left(\left(\dfrac{10}{4}+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)\pi\right),\ \,\sin\left(\dfrac{11}{4}\pi\right)=\sin\left(\left(\dfrac{10}{4}+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)\pi\right).$$

Comment: You don't say? ${}$

Comment: @BozoVulicevic What do you mean? My hint was to help you evaluating the cosines and sines that appear in your expression.

Answer (score 1):

The binomial quantities being raised to powers are easy to simplify: $$\sqrt[6]{\frac{\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}}$$

Now it's quite easy to continue. $$\sqrt[6]{\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}}=\sqrt[6]{-1}$$